# Can't input data to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'am developing a system, but I've a problem in registration page. member data can't input to database. no message error
This is  my view

```
<?php $this->load->view('notification') ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('register/post') ?>">
    <div class="input-place">
        <label>
            Kartu Pengenal 
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <select name="kartupengenal" id="show" onchange="sesuaikantandapengenal(this.value)">
            <option selected="selected">-- Pilih Salah Satu--</option>

            <?php foreach($kartupengenal as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['identitasid'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nama'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-place">
        <label>
            No Identitas
            <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="ktp" class="form-control" name="noidentitas" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" id="sim" class="form-control" name="noidentitas" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" id="ktm" class="form-control" name="noidentitas" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" id="passport" class="form-control" name="noidentitas" style="display:none">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Daftar</button>
</form>
```

And then this controller

```
//controller code register.php
public function post()
    { 
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');

        if($this->_validation()==FALSE){
            redirect(base_url('register'));
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Pendaftaran gagal, silahkan coba kembali!');
        }else{
            $data = array(  'identitas'     => $this->input->post('kartupengenal'),
                            'noidentitas'   => $this->input->post('noidentitas')
                         );
            $this->model_user->post($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Pendaftaran berhasil');
            redirect(base_url('auth/login'));
        }
    }

    public function _validation(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('kartupengenal','Nama Panggilan', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('noidentitas','Nomor Identitas', 'numberic|trim|required|xss_clean');
        return $this->form_validation->run();
    }
```

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('noidentitas','Nomor Identitas', 'numberic|trim|required|xss_clean');` --> its only save a last id of identitasid, if I choose identitas id 1 until 3 it can't save data. How do to fix its ?

thanks before advance

Comment: why your all input type="text" has same name 'noidentitas'????

Comment: I've changed with another name but still it can not be entered into the database

Comment: any type of error and where is your model file?

Comment: no message error appears 
`code` public function post($data){
        $this->db->insert('tbl_users', $data);
    }

Comment: have you call model file in your constructor??

Comment: Yes, I've been call model in my constructor

Comment: submit your edited code

Comment: Controller --> [1]: http://pastebin.com/Rdp4mt8C

View -->  [1]: http://pastebin.com/7Rp7Yx8c

Comment: controller looks okk. Have your code enter into model file use die in model  post function and check

Comment: Yes, I've entered its

Comment: it means something wrong in model file and not able to open your view file

Comment: only need your model file function post

Comment: which makes me confused is only the last identitasid that can be stored while 1 to 3 can not be stored data

Comment: identitasid is numeric or string value?

Answer (score 0):

mybe this code can help you.
code : view

```
<form action="http://heloo.com/contact" method="post">
     <fieldset>
          {error_msg}
          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name*">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail*">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject*">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
               <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-cons">Send Message</button>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

code : controller

```
public function contact() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $this->load->library('form_validation'); //Load library.

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name',    'Username', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[45]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email',   'E-mail',   'required|min_length[1]|max_length[100]|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject',  'required|min_length[1]|max_length[45]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message',  'required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $this->load->model('Contact_Us');
            $input['i_name'] = $this->input->post('name', TRUE);
            $input['i_email'] = $this->input->post('email', TRUE);
            $input['i_subject'] = $this->input->post('subject', TRUE);
            $input['i_message'] = $this->input->post('message', TRUE);
             $this->Contact_Us->save_contact($input);
        }else {
            //Set error message.
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', validation_errors());
            redirect('contact');
        }
    }else {
        //another code
    }
}
```

code : models

```
public function save_contact($input = array()) {
    $this->db->set('t_name', $input['i_name']);
    $this->db->set('t_email', $input['i_email']);
    $this->db->set('t_subject', $input['i_subject']);
    $this->db->set('t_message', $input['i_message']);
    $this->db->insert('contact');
}
```

read this documentation here :

```
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html
```

Answer (score -1):

check every post values are echo on form post.

`print_r($this->input->post());`